# Trouble with iFrame.contentDocument

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

Basically, im making a javascript to refresh a page and it will find the price and buy the item when it goes up for the price desired.

I got it to work without the iframe, but I need to to work in the iframe, which is the problem ive reached.

If you went to this page: [ http://m.roblox.com/items/100933289/privatesales ]

and ran this code:

```
alert(document.getElementsByClassName('currency-robux')[0].innerHTML);
```

You would get an alert for the lowest price. In the code, this doesnt work (Hence, my problem.)

Try running the code below on this page to get it to work [ http://www.roblox.com/Junk-Bot-item?id=100933289 ]

```
var filePath = document.URL;
var itemid = filePath.slice(((filePath.search("="))+1));
var mobileRoot = 'http://m.roblox.com/items/';
var mobileEnd = '/privatesales';
var mobileFilePath = mobileRoot+itemid+mobileEnd;

var iframe2 = '<iframe id="frame" width="100%" height="1" scrolling="yes"></iframe>';
document.write(iframe2);
var iframe = parent.document.getElementById("frame");
iframe.height = 300;
iframe.width = 500;
iframe.src = mobileFilePath;
var price;
var snipe = false;
var lp = Number(prompt("Snipe Price?"));
document.title = "Sniping";

function takeOutCommas(s){
    var str = s;
    while ((str.indexOf(",")) !== -1){
        str = str.replace(",","");
    }
    return str;
}

function load() {
    if (snipe == false) {
        tgs = iframe.contentDocument.getElementsByClassName('currency-robux');
        price = Number((takeOutCommas(tgs[0].innerHTML)));
        alert(price);
    }
}

iframe.onload = load;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try having both pages — the one from "m.roblox.com" and the one from "www.roblox.com" — add the following up at the top of the head:

```
<script>
  document.domain = "roblox.com";
</script>
```

Code from the different domains won't be allowed to look at each others page contents, but if you set the domains to the same suffix then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get it to work by sharing the same `document.domain="roblox.com"` code then you can try posting messages to the iframe.

Put this inside the iframe page:

```
window.addEventListener('message',function(e) {
});
```

In the parent page execute this to pass a message (can be a string or object, anything really) to the iframe:

```
document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.postMessage({ "json_example": true }, "*");
```

Put this in the parent to listen for the message:

```
window.addEventListener("message", messageReceived, false);
function messageReceived(e) {
}
```

From inside the iframe posting a message back out:

```
window.parent.postMessage('Hello Parent Page','*');
```